# .next method python 3.6

Tags: python, encoding, linked-list

The following is a code to reverse a linked list.
My problem is this code results in a error saying list doesn't have an attribute of next. 
Then I try to generate an iterate by using iter(). The error becomes ''list_iterator' object has no attribute 'next''

What is the usage of method .next here?

```
a=[6,5,4,3,2,1,]
iter_a=iter(a)


def reverse_iterative(head):
# no need to reverse if head is null 
# or there is only 1 node.
if (head == None or 
    head.next == None):
  return head

list_to_do = head.next

reversed_list = head
reversed_list.__next = None

while (list_to_do != None):
  temp = list_to_do
  list_to_do = list_to_do.next

  temp.next = reversed_list
  reversed_list = temp

return reversed_list
```

Comment: Python use function not methods, so you have `len(a)`, `str(b)`, and also `next(c)`. But iterator next consume the item.

Comment: `next` methods in 2.x were renamed `__next__` in 3.x.  Use the `next` built-in function.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `.next()` method on a list or an iterator.  You're looking for the `next(...)` builtin.

Try this:

```
iterator = iter(list_to_do)
while True:
    try:
        item = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        break

    # do stuff with `item`
```

I'm assuming you're doing this to learn the internals of iterators, but if you're not, please just use a for loop:

```
for item in list_to_do:
    pass
```

Or even better, just use `reversed()`:

```
reversed(list_to_do)
```